# using php and curl for phishing demo

Tags: php, mysql, curl, phishing

I have created a phishing site (for demonstration) that is identical to the login of the site that I am trying to copy. When you submit your username and password, it uses php to save them in a mysql database. Right now, it just redirects you to an error page (that I created) after it saves the info. I was thinking, to make this site more advanced, I could use the login data I saved and redirect people to the real site ALREADY LOGGED IN so its as if my site was the real one and nobody would know. I did some researching and found cURL but Im still not entirely sure how to use it in my case. I want to redirect people to the real site and log them in with the info they typed in on my phishing site. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hopefully that is not possible. If you find a site where such thing work, then that site has a mile wide security gap so there is not really any point in taking a closer look at that. But what I don't understand: why don't you simply ask that sites owner how to do that? I mean he should be happy for you testing his sites security, so you certainly will get a positive response.

Comment: authentication is normaly done with cookies. as you cant set cookies for different domains. this would not be posible. I can think of 1 other way it could be posible but i dont want to give "hacking" instructions.